# Event capturing with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

jQuery uses event bubbling, but is there a way to do event capturing i.e. in the descending order as explained [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

The specific case is the following  where host A and host B are on the same domain like :
`www.example.com` and `xxx.example.com`.
Of course the Same Origin Policy makes it that it is not possible to trigger on event in the iframe. However I just would like to know if user has clicked on `$('#hostA')` and pass on the event to the `<iframe>`.

```
 <div id="hostA">
  <iframe id="hostB">
</div>
```

Comment: You can traverse down yourself; see http://jsfiddle.net/7u87c/72/ 
**Note:** I didn't write the html/css; it is from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20415790/578023)

Answer (score 5):

No, jQuery does not support this and it never can -- IE has no way to implement a capturing event.

Comment: I can do if it only works on FF or Chrome. Would there be a solution in that case.

Comment: FYI, this isn't what you asked, but if you run this from both frames, you'll be able to trigger events cross-sub domain: `document.domain = document.domain.replace(/.*?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$/, '$1');`

Comment: per the Mozilla docs, addEventListner has a capturing property.  You could theoretically modify jQuery's `.bind` to use this if you desire.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: @cwolves IE9 and below doesn't support addEventListener.

Comment: Sorry, need to clarify: below IE9 doesn't support it.  IE9 supports it, but only on standards mode.