# Is it possible to trigger a DOM event and make it go down in the DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The current dom event model propagates the event from a leaf node (the source of the event) to the top root (document).

My question is this: Is there a way to trigger an event backwards? From body, make it go down the dom to the leaves?

I want to disable all form inputs in my form. They are all jquery ui widgets. I don't keep a reference of the elements in the main form component and when I submit I want to disable all of them. All my widgets bind to a custom dom event, called "field:disable".

Comment: why do you want to capture event instead of bubbling it, [jquery does not support capturing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354079/event-capturing-with-jquery)

Comment: Why not `$("input").disable()`?

Comment: why don't you do `$('#form input').triggerHandler('field:disable')`

Comment: @WaleedKhan, I have custom widgets like dropdowns, comboboxes and spinners.

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeah, I think that's the way to go. Not to pleased about it for some reason but it will have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery [does not support event capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354079/event-capturing-with-jquery), so I think you are stuck with event bubbling.

Why don't you do

```
$('#form input').trigger('field:disable')
```

if you do not want to propagate the event

```
$('#form input').triggerHandler('field:disable')
```

Comment: I was thinking that capture trigger would be less costing compared to a jQuery selector. Oh well, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Events can only bubble from leaf to root, not the other way around.

You should determine a common class that all your widgets have and then trigger the event manually:

```
$('.ui-widget').trigger('field:disable');
```