# event.target and event capturing

Tags: jquery, events, event-bubbling, event-capturing

I'm very new to jquery and I'm currently reading "learning jQuery" I have a question regarding event capturing and event.target.

I have the html code like this:

```
<div id="switcher" class="switcher">
        <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
        <button id="switcher-default">
          Default
        </button>
        <button id="switcher-narrow">
          Narrow Column
        </button>
        <button id="switcher-large">
          Large Print
        </button>
</div>
```

According to [event capturing with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354079/event-capturing-with-jquery)
jQuery doesn't support event capturing and only support bubbling. Which means, if both buttons and div element are binded to the click event and when I click on the button, button's click will call first, then the div, and since event capturing is not supported, which means if I click on the div area, button's click function will NOT be called.

However, if I add something like this:

```
$("#switcher").click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target);
});
```

and if I click on the button, the event target will be the button. If the selector $("#switcher") only select the div element, then how come when I click on the button, it alerts the event.target? I thought when I click on the button, the above jQuery will not be called at all?

Comment: Because events bubble. When you click on teh button, the event happens on the button, and then bubbles up to the div.

Comment: And that's why `if (event.target === this)` works to avoid that issue.

Comment: what I don't understand is, I got that alert message when I clicked on the button, even I didn't add any click event to the button