# Pure css tree with borders

Tags: css

I am trying to create a tree with indentations in pure CSS. I have been trying using something like:

```
ul.tree ul {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

However I would like to have a separation between each item in the list. If I use the code above the separating bar gets indented as well so it's not too good.

Here is my current code (I do the indent directly in js, which I don't like): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7u87c/)

Ultimately, I want to create something that basically looks like that:

[image: tree example]

Any idea how to do this in pure CSS? kudos for the simplest answers.

Comment: Please include your HTML (and any other relevant CSS). Thanks!

Comment: @showdev: I added a jdfiddle

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. If your parent ul has a padding, the child (ul > ul) will also be affected so just setting the ul to have a padding will cascade through the children ul too. - See http://jsfiddle.net/7u87c/19/

Comment: @Daniel I think the trick is the separating lines and how to indent the lists without indenting the lines.

Comment: @showdev - Ahh, mine was a little over simple then. ScottS appears to have the answer.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I like ScottS's answer quite a bit. The only caveat (in addition to the limitations he lists in his answer) is that it's [not fully compatible with very old versions of IE](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2). But that may or may not be an issue, depending on the project.

Comment: Well if your client is concerned about IE5.5, I would politely tell them to go swivel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Simple with Multi-level Depth Support

**UPDATED: Tweaked to accommodate hover**

**No extra HTML needed, no having to limit depth because of css selector chaining, as it supports any number of levels deep without having to adjust your css at all for those levels (no keeping track of "padding" to set on the next level deep).**

This works well with only a two minor limitations (which I don't believe will factor into affecting you).

[**See fiddle demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7u87c/54/)

Add a `position: relative` to your `ul.tree`, but keep all the child elements the default `static` position. Then change/add the following css:

```
ul.tree a {
  display: block;
  height:30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

/* this is making our bottom border, but sizing off the .tree ul width */
ul.tree a:before { 
  content: '';
  height: 30px; /* match your <a> height */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: lightgray;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}


ul.tree a + ul {
    padding-left: 15px; /* this is your spacing for each level */
}

ul.tree a:hover:before {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

The limitations are that no child elements can have a position set and we are using a pseudo-element (which means it cannot be used for some other feature, but that is probably not an issue either).

Comment: I was trying to mess around with `:before` to get the same effect, but gave up. Kudos to you!

Comment: Very nice and clean! I went ahead and checked out how it would go traversing with jQuery. vanilla JS events would be similar of course. Anyway, might be handy for someone else using AJAX along with your trees. http://jsfiddle.net/7u87c/72/

Answer (score 3):

For lists with unknown depths, I've used an absolutely positioned element for separating lines. It adds a little extra markup, but seems to work.

```
div.separator {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    border-top:1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li><a>Item1</a><div class="separator"></div></li>
    <li><a>Item2</a><div class="separator"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Item3</a><div class="separator"></div></li>
            <li><a>Item4</a><div class="separator"></div></li>
            <li><a>Item5</a><div class="separator"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Item6</a><div class="separator"></div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7u87c/20/

Comment: Very good answer according to me. Supports any depth of indentation.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS makes the link inside a nested `li` have a `padding-left` of `30px`, and I add another nested `li` link have `padding-left: 60px`.

```
ul.tree li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

ul.tree li ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7u87c/5/

Comment: Indentation level is hard coded here at two levels deep in css via `ul.tree li ul li ul li a`. So each time you add a new level of indentation, a css change is required! Not very optimal unless the indentation is fixed at 2 levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

No extra markup and use of icon image.

Pretty simple and dynamic based on the content.

Sample HTML:

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li><span>public</span></li>
    <li><span>server.js</span></li>
    <li>
        <span>server</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>webfs</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>specs</span></li>
    <li>
        <span>src</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>core</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>CellAddress.js</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.tree {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

ul.tree, ul.tree ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul span {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/10/8/") no-repeat scroll 5px 8px transparent;
}

ul ul span {
    padding-left: 35px;
    background-position: 15px 8px; 
}

ul ul ul span {
    padding-left: 45px;
    background-position: 25px 8px;
}
```

Please [see example](http://jsfiddle.net/nqJEA/1/)

Note: You can convert the `spans` into `a` tags